# How to enable MySQL client auto re-connect with MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql

I came across PHP way of doing the trick:

```
my_bool reconnect = 1;
mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
```

but no luck with MySQLdb (python-mysql).

Can anybody please give a clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 81):

I solved this problem by creating a function that wraps the `cursor.execute()` method since that's what was throwing the `MySQLdb.OperationalError` exception. The other example above implies that it is the `conn.cursor()` method that throws this exception.

```
import MySQLdb

class DB:
  conn = None

  def connect(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect()

  def query(self, sql):
    try:
      cursor = self.conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute(sql)
    except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
      self.connect()
      cursor = self.conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute(sql)
    return cursor

db = DB()
sql = "SELECT * FROM foo"
cur = db.query(sql)
# wait a long time for the Mysql connection to timeout
cur = db.query(sql)
# still works
```

Comment: @garret-heaton - why reconnect on AttributeError? Is that also thrown when the connection becomes stale?

Comment: For quite some time I tried to figure out occasional mysql errors in my wrapper. Initially I thought `conn.open` will do the trick nope... but this worked.

Comment: If you re-connect, you should be aware that you have lost any `@variables` and `SETtings`.  Also, a half-finished transaction will have been `ROLLBACK`'d.  This can lead to some messes.

Comment: @aaa90210: The AttributeError is to catch the case where self.conn is still 'None' (the db hasn't been connected to yet) and the query method tries 'cursor = self.conn.cursor()'.

Comment: @RickJames I understand what you're saying, but don't **most** timeouts have to do with the connection being idle for a long time, meaning the problem you mention would be rare?

Comment: @ckot - "Idle" is relative.  If you get a project started, then take a coffee break, or compute something that takes a long time, and then come back, you may find that the connection is closed -- because _from MySQL's point of view_ it was idle.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this will also catch other errors: `OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'countryy' in 'field list'").` Maybe this was different back in 2009, but just saying.

Answer (score 22):

I had problems with the proposed solution because it didn't catch the exception. I am not sure why.

I have solved the problem with the `ping(True)` statement which I think is neater:

```
import MySQLdb
con=MySQLdb.Connect()
con.ping(True)
cur=con.cursor()
```

Got it from here: http://www.neotitans.com/resources/python/mysql-python-connection-error-2006.html

Comment: I was spawning my script into 16-20 subprocesses, and i was having problems with mysql gone away. The con.ping(True) fixed my issue.Thanks.

Comment: Pinging before running a query is considered an anti-pattern that wastes resources and is unreliable: https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/05/05/checking-for-a-live-database-connection-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 11):

If you are using ubuntu Linux there was a patch added to the python-mysql package that added the ability to set that same MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT option (see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+source/python-mysqldb/1.2.2-5)).  I have not tried it though.

Unfortunately, the patch was later removed due to a conflict with autoconnect and transations (described [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-mysqldb)).

The comments from that page say:
1.2.2-7 Published in intrepid-release on 2008-06-19

python-mysqldb (1.2.2-7) unstable; urgency=low

[ Sandro Tosi ]
  * debian/control
    - list items lines in description starts with 2 space, to avoid reformat
      on webpages (Closes: #480341)

[ Bernd Zeimetz ]
  * debian/patches/02_reconnect.dpatch:
    - Dropping patch:
      Comment in Storm which explains the problem:

```
    # Here is another sad story about bad transactional behavior. MySQL
    # offers a feature to automatically reconnect dropped connections.
    # What sounds like a dream, is actually a nightmare for anyone who
    # is dealing with transactions. When a reconnection happens, the
    # currently running transaction is transparently rolled back, and
    # everything that was being done is lost, without notice. Not only
    # that, but the connection may be put back in AUTOCOMMIT mode, even
    # when that's not the default MySQLdb behavior. The MySQL developers
    # quickly understood that this is a terrible idea, and removed the
    # behavior in MySQL 5.0.3. Unfortunately, Debian and Ubuntu still
    # have a patch right now which *reenables* that behavior by default
    # even past version 5.0.3.
```

Comment: I guess whatever the client does, a lost connection may indicate loss of a transaction (server power cycled) or loss of connectivity.  So I agree that simple re-connecting may hide loss of data against expectation of mysql client user.

Answer (score 7):

I needed a solution that works similarly to Garret's, but for `cursor.execute()`, as I want to let `MySQLdb` handle all escaping duties for me.  The wrapper module ended up looking like this (usage below):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb

class DisconnectSafeCursor(object):
    db = None
    cursor = None

    def __init__(self, db, cursor):
        self.db = db
        self.cursor = cursor

    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()

    def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.cursor.execute(*args, **kwargs)
        except MySQLdb.OperationalError:
            self.db.reconnect()
            self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
            return self.cursor.execute(*args, **kwargs)

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchone()

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

class DisconnectSafeConnection(object):
    connect_args = None
    connect_kwargs = None
    conn = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.connect_args = args
        self.connect_kwargs = kwargs
        self.reconnect()

    def reconnect(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(*self.connect_args, **self.connect_kwargs)

    def cursor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cur = self.conn.cursor(*args, **kwargs)
        return DisconnectSafeCursor(self, cur)

    def commit(self):
        self.conn.commit()

    def rollback(self):
        self.conn.rollback()

disconnectSafeConnect = DisconnectSafeConnection
```

Using it is trivial, only the initial connect differs.  Extend the classes with wrapper methods as per your MySQLdb needs.

```
import mydb

db = mydb.disconnectSafeConnect()
# ... use as a regular MySQLdb.connections.Connection object

cursor = db.cursor()

# no more "2006: MySQL server has gone away" exceptions now
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar=%s", ("baz",))
```

Comment: This should be the first answer. Much more powerful than the rest.

Comment: Really nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can separate the commit and the close for the connection...that's not cute but it does it.

```
class SqlManager(object):
 """
 Class that handle the database operation
 """
 def __init__(self,server, database, username, pswd):

      self.server = server
      self.dataBase = database
      self.userID = username
      self.password = pswd

def Close_Transation(self):
      """
      Commit the SQL Query
      """
      try:
        self.conn.commit()
      except Sql.Error, e:
        print "-- reading SQL Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

 def Close_db(self):
    try:
        self.conn.close()
    except Sql.Error, e:
        print "-- reading SQL Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

 def __del__(self):
    print "close connection with database.."
    self.conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with MySQL and Python, and the solution that worked for me was to upgrade MySQL to 5.0.27 (on Fedora Core 6; your system may work fine with a different version).

I tried a lot of other things, including patching the Python libraries, but upgrading the database was a lot easier and (I think) a better decision.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Liviu Chircu solution ... add the following method to DisconnectSafeCursor:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.cursor, name)
```

and the original cursor properties like "lastrowid" will keep working.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is based on [Liviu Chircu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054305/liviu-chircu) solution.

I have added control over **too many retries**. The original answer from Liviu  can easily get to a "**Too many connections**" ***OperationalError*** if a query doesn't match the fields in the table's structure.

```
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'xxxxxxx' in 'field list'")
```

This error **is not a connection error**. In my version, I have removed also the class variables as I believe they are not necessary.

```
import MySQLdb


class MySQLdbReconnectableCursor(object):
    def __init__(self, db, cursor):
        self.db = db
        self.cursor = cursor

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.cursor, name)

    def __iter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.cursor.__iter__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.cursor.__next__(*args, **kwargs)

    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()

    def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = self.cursor.execute(*args, **kwargs)
            self.db.refresh_retries()
            return result
        except MySQLdb.OperationalError:
            self.db.reconnect(reraise=True)
            self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
            return self.cursor.execute(*args, **kwargs)

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchone()

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchall()


class MySQLdbReconnectable(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.conn = None
        self.retries = kwargs.get("max_retries", 3)
        self.connect_args = args
        self.connect_kwargs = kwargs
        self.refresh_retries()
        self.reconnect()

    def refresh_retries(self):
        self.__retries = self.retries

    def reconnect(self, reraise=False):
        if self.__retries:
            self.__retries -= 1
            self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(
                *self.connect_args, **self.connect_kwargs
            )
        else:
            if reraise:
                raise
            else:
                raise IOError("Can not retry anymore!")

    def cursor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cur = self.conn.cursor(*args, **kwargs)
        return MySQLdbReconnectableCursor(self, cur)

    def commit(self):
        self.conn.commit()

    def rollback(self):
        self.conn.rollback()
```

Answer (score -4):

You other bet it to work around dropped connections yourself with code.

One way to do it would be the following:

```
import MySQLdb

class DB:
    conn = None

    def connect(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect()

    def cursor(self):
        try:
            return self.conn.cursor()
        except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
            self.connect()
            return self.conn.cursor()

db = DB()
cur = db.cursor()
# wait a long time for the Mysql connection to timeout
cur = db.cursor()
# still works
```

Comment: Actually this one doesn't work. Creating a cursor doesn't make a connection with the DB and therefore doesn't throw the OperationError exception.