# Django improperly loading while restarting it

Tags: mysql, django

I have a website that is in VPS hosting. I was supposed to restart it with the following code

```
source .venv/bin/activate
uwsgi --ini agros.ini
```

But I am receiving the following error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

here is the database configuration in the `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 3600,
    'NAME': 'agros_new',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 3309,
 }
}
```

this website uses Django version = `1.9` and the operating system is the `Centos OS`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444272/error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-using-python-bottle-microframework-and

Comment: Post the MySQL error log and it is likely someone can assist.