# How to fix MySQL Server has gone away error in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I am running a live detection python script. So the python script runs 24/7 without closing but after few hours, I get `MySQL has hone away` error

This is my code to make connection

```
def connectToMySQL(config_str):
    return mysql.connector.connect(
        host=config_str[1].strip('\n').strip('\r\n'),
        user=config_str[2].strip('\n').strip('\r\n'),
        passwd=config_str[3].strip('\n').strip('\r\n'),
        database=config_str[4].strip('\n').strip('\r\n')
    )
mydb = connectToMySQL(config_str)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

How can i set the timeout limit to infinity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable MySQL client auto re-connect with MySQLdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207981/how-to-enable-mysql-client-auto-re-connect-with-mysqldb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: 1.) It do not use mysql-connector 2.) It is not even related to python.

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem while using connection in multi threaded enviroment. i fixed it by making connection again from the each thread (and closing it in it).

Comment: worked for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below queries in MySQL.

```
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=31536000;
SET @@GLOBAL.interactive_timeout=31536000;
```

(for windows use 2147483 value)

Restart MySQL server.

Also, make sure to close the cursor and connection after using it.

```
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```